# VSTS Build Failure - error MSB4184: The expression """.ArtifactsStagingDirectory" cannot be evaluated

Tags: azure-devops, build-error

I have a solution with multiple projects (1 WebApi project, 2 MVC projects, and bunch of class libraries).

I am following [this](https://thaddparker.wordpress.com/2017/02/17/building-multiple-projects-and-pushing-to-octopus-deploy-with-build-vnext/) article on using Octopus Deploy to package up individual projects and push them to the Octopus server when the projects are contained in a single solution.

The build solution tasks has me changing the arguments from:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(BuildConfiguration)"
```

to

```
/p:OutDir=$(Build.ArtifactsStagingDirectory) /p:GenerateProjectSpecficOutputFolder=true
```

on the surface this makes sense - publish everything to a single directory and create a separate folder for each project.

However changing this - creates and error on build:

> d:\a\1\s\Test.Models\Test.Models.csproj" (default target) (5) ->
>   (ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades target) ->    C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.NetFramework.CurrentVersion.targets(107,74):
>   error MSB4184: The expression """.ArtifactsStagingDirectory" cannot be
>   evaluated. Method 'System.String.ArtifactsStagingDirectory' not found.
>   [d:\a\1\s\Test.Models\P4P.Models.csproj]

This is a separate class library that is failing.  The solution is building one of the web applications and another class library before reaching this failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$(Build.ArtifactsStagingDirectory)` you specified is not a predefined variable. There is a redundant string "s" in it. The right one should be: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`.